# Meteor audit-argument-checks

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor project where I'm using audit-argument-check. I'm getting an error message

```
Error: Did not check() all arguments during publisher 'document
```

I'm know this is related the audit-argument-check not being able to check all arguments. But as far as I'm concerned, I checked all of them. Concrete, I have defined a collection 'documents' and attached a SimpleSchema. As part of iron-router, I have the following:

```
Router.route('customerDocumentShow', {
    template: 'customerDocumentShow',
    path: 'customer/documents/:_id',
    waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('document', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {
      return Documents.findOne(this.params._id);
    }
  });
```

So I'm passing only the documentId (this.params._id). On the server, I have defined a method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  documentsReadMethod: function(documentId){
    check(documentId, String);

    var documentItem = Document.findOne(argument);

    if (!documentItem) {
      throw new Meteor.Error(500, 'Error 500: Not Found', 'No documents found.');
    }

    return documentItem;
  }
});
```

So I'm checking to documentId in the server method. So not sure why I'm getting this error message.

Note: One thing I'm not entirely sure about though is how I need to call this method (right now, it's documentsReadMethod_. I'm not explicitly calling (on the client):

```
Meteor.call(documentsReadMethod, this.params_id);
```

as I'm using autoform, collection2 and simpleschema. I've been spending the entire weekend, but have no clue. Any idea's ?

Note: the code is on github: https://github.com/wymedia/meteor-starter-base

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the publish. You didn't check the id here:

https://github.com/wymedia/meteor-starter-base/blob/master/server/publications/documents.js#L16

Just add `check(id, String);` line 16 and it should work.

Comment: Hi @acemtp, thank you very much. That works indeed perfect. Quick question though on the Meteor.methods. So I have done an allow/deny on the client side, as well as Meteor.methods, but I don't have the impression they get executed. Any clue why? I would like to have a server side validation and preferably not having to use allow/deny

Comment: You mix 2 concepts: 1/ publish / subscribe / allow / deny : handle the data flow and 2/ methods / call: a remote procedure call system.
your method will be called only if you execute on the client Meteor.call('documentsReadMethod', id);

Comment: I understand. So is the conclusion that with Autoform, you can only use allow/deny (as you don't explicitly call Meteor.call using autoform)?

Comment: You can use meteor.call / methods with autoform, but it's not the default behavior. Check the example on their doc: https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-autoform#an-example-contact-form

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with another tuto !

Answer found  at [check is not defined in meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521059/check-is-not-defined-in-meteor-js) : since Meteor v1.2, you have to add this package:

```
$ meteor add check
```