# check is not defined in meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor, I was trying to use file upload using 
[tomitrescak/meteor-uploads](https://github.com/tomitrescak/meteor-uploads)

I successfully uploaded some file, but when I tried to delete the uploaded file, I got error in my terminal **Reference Error:check is not defined**

I have checked the documentation and searched the web regarding this error but could not find any solution for this.

Note: I got similar error while studing http://meteortips.com/second-meteor-tutorial/iron-router-part-1/

OS: Ubuntu 14.04
meteor: 1.2.1

Comment: Do you use `check` anywhere in your code or does this error pop up when you use some features of said packages?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
$ meteor add check
```

## Longer version

In Meteor version prior to v1.2, a core package called `meteor-platform` used to export some symbols, including `check`.

Since v1.2, [this is no longer the case](https://quip.com/RXFlAk9Rc2xI) and those symbols are no longer available via the platform, but using dedicated packages instead.

It is likely that one of the packages that you are using (or your app code itself) is using `check` (probably in one of its methods) without declaring it as a dependency.

Until the package maintainers update the dependency, you should be able to overcome the error by adding `check` as a top-level dependency:

```
$ meteor add check
```

If you identify which package is causing the issue, you can report it on GitHub, or fork the package yourself, add the missing dependencies and submit a pull-request.

Comment: They really should address/mention this in the tutorial.  Thanks!